# Run a scheduled task when a user changes the desktop background

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, desktop-customization

I have a logon script deployed via GPO that changes the users desktop background to a company default, while also adding information via `BGinfo` that is useful for helpdesk calls.

However, users sometimes work out how to change the desktop backgorund and both the company branding and the info derived from `BGinfo` are lost.

I was originally trying to trigger my script via the `Task Scheduler` using a logged event, but it looks like Windwows doees not audit this activity.

I have also looked at GP, specifically `Windows Settings\Security Settings\Advanced Audit Policy Configuration`, but I cannot see any setting in there that would audit a change to the desktop background.

Is it possible to audit this activity in Windows, and if so, is it possible to trigger a scheduled task when the event occurs? Thanks.

Comment: you should be applying a GP that disallows wallpaper change.

Comment: @pulsarjune - I am, but with Windows being Windows there always seems to be a way around these things. For example, the laptop is not connected to the network when the user logs on, thus the policy cannot be retrieved.

Comment: [This might be of some help](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000461.htm) if you are planning **GPOs**. Once applied, users cant do anything about this- even if they are off network. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537836/how-can-i-detect-wallpaper-changing-as-a-result-of-the-windows-7-slideshow) discussion might be of some help, if you are a code guy

Comment: Cheers, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to audit this activity in Windows, and if so, is it possible to trigger a scheduled task when the event occurs?

There is no in-built way to audit the desktop background being changed.

You would probably have to write a utility/service, and distribute it to all the computers to monitor for the change.  Here's a StackoOverflow question that can help with that: [How does one detect when the wallpaper has changed (Windows XP or greater)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014542/how-does-one-detect-when-the-wallpaper-has-changed-windows-xp-or-greater)

As @pulsarjune suggests in his comment, you should be using existing GP capabilities to [prevent the users from being able to change their wallpaper](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000461.htm).

> For example, the laptop is not connected to the network when the user logs on, thus the policy cannot be retrieved

Policy is retrieved and then set in the client. If they then go off-network the policies still apply as-is, they just won't get any new/changed polices until the next time they connect to the domain.

Having said all this, if you give the user's Administrator permissions on their computers, all bets are off and you might as well just give up now. :)